# Difficult integral with dirac comb

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta

I'm trying to solve the following integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\pi (x+1))}{x}[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\delta (x-n)]dx$

So this seems pretty terrible, and there is also a hint

Hint: "Don't be afraid". Nevertheless, I am afraid.

How do you start solving this? I know I'm supposed to show some effort, but I really have no idea where to start. Maybe integration by parts?

Comment: Do you know what $\cos(n \pi)$ evaluates to for an integer number $n$?

Comment: What would the answer be if you replaced the sum of deltas with one delta?

Comment: Ofcourse. It's $(-1)^{n}$

Comment: Do you know what the delta distribution does to functions? It may be better for you to consider $\sum_{n=0}^N \delta (x-n)$, do the integral and then take the limit $N \to \infty$.

Comment: It should cancel out all the none integer values so the integrand is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n$ correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with cancelling out the non-integer values, but in general the delta distribution acts on continuous functions in the following way: $\int dx\, f(x)\, \delta (x-y) = f(y)$ if $y$ is in the domain which is being integrated over. A (finite) sum of delta functions acts in the same way. Also, don't forget the factor $1/x$ in your integrand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We simply use the ["sifting" property of the Dirac Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation) to obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\pi(x+1))}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\delta(x-n)\,dx&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\pi(n+1))}{n}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\\\\
&=\log 2
\end{align}$$